# Material design table with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got table with checkboxes but I don't know how to do something while checkbox is checked.

```
<md-table-container>
            <table md-table md-row-select multiple ng-model="selected" md-progress="promise">
                <thead md-head>
                    <tr md-row>
                        <th md-column></th>
                        <th md-column>ID</th>
                        <th md-column>Username</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody md-body>
                    <tr md-row md-select="user" md-select-id="id" md-auto-select ng-repeat="user in users">
                        <td md-cell></td>
                        <td md-cell><span>{{ user.id }}</span></td>
                        <td md-cell>{{ user.username }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </md-table-container>
```

How Can I check that checkbox is checked and do something?

Comment: Javascript is the solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

add `$scope.$watch` on the variable that you are interested in (or `watchcollection`)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Do not forget that variable you are watching is in $scope and propagation of variable into ng-if scopes happen by copying not reference. You can wrap variable into some container object, otherwise changes will happen in another scope and you never notice them.

Comment: It works:
http://pastebin.com/x7javKk2

While I check checkbox is set: 1 item selected
But is possible to run fuction here?

Comment: @Radekesd the piece of code you are showing is html/template that is UI side, the $scope.$watch should be implemented in controller. Every digest it checks if variable was changed and run your function in case of change.